# Can i merge spring boot with other languages

Tags: spring-boot

I wanted to ask is it possible to increase the speed of a spring-boot app with a language such as C++, C or python just as other frameworks can?.

Comment: Technically you can use C code with Java, by using JNI. But the number of usecases where this really makes sense is quite limited, and i don't think that you would use Spring Boot for those use cases. What performance problems do you have? What does your application do?

Comment: @dunni  its a mini social network like facebook, basically u can only store one picture for the profile picture, and send messages via websockets chats and send money via a solution provider, thats basically it. and i want it to support a huge traffic and want to know if spring mvc can carry it.